# Is there a limit to the number of indexes an ElasticSearch alias can point to?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this alias that I want to point to 60 indexes. At 21 indexes, I start getting Execution Rejected exceptions.

Is this because of a 20 index limit in the alias API?

Comment: Did you modify thread pool settings by any chance?

Comment: Yep. Do you think one of these could lead to this issue?

threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 16

threadpool.search.type: fixed
threadpool.search.size: 32
threadpool.search.queue: 100

threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have 5 shards per index, a request against 21 indices may generates about 105 shard requests, 32 of these requests are sent to threads in the pool and 73 request go into the queue. At this moment you have only about 27 elements in the queue left. So, if another request against 6 or more indices (30 shards) arrives, some shardsrequests are going to be rejected with Execution Rejected Exception. I am oversimplifying the situation here quite a bit and the actual number of threads used depends on many factors including where shards are located, search settings, etc. However, I hope you can see the main idea here: if you want to search against a large number of shards, you need to make sure you have enough capacity in the thread pool to handle the peak load.