# How many indices an alias can have in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Well I have a requirement to have daily rolling indices and to search on all indices, I have an alias which maps to all indices that are ever created.

But as the time passes, there are going to be lot of indices, so wanted to know if there is a limit on the number of indices an alias can point to?

Is so what is that limit and any alternative to mitigate this?
Also heard of alias for aliases, will that solve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit of the number of aliases (globally and/or per index) in elasticsearch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106626/is-there-a-limit-of-the-number-of-aliases-globally-and-or-per-index-in-elastic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing from [Is there a limit to the number of indexes an ElasticSearch alias can point to?](http://Is%20there%20a%20limit%20to%20the%20number%20of%20indexes%20an%20ElasticSearch%20alias%20can%20point%20to?)

> There's no such hard limit on the number of indices an alias can point to. Although other resources like open
>   connections, max thread pool size, number of Shards per index etc
>   could lead to a failure.

[Another Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554845/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-indexes-an-elasticsearch-alias-can-point-to)